# Rails, sprockets, google closure and advanced opts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-closure-compiler, sprockets

I've added the closure-compiler gem to my Gemfile and set

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :closure
```

in the config/environments/production.rb file.

I believe this defaults to using the SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS compilation level and I was wondering if there is a config variable I can set somewhere to specify the advanced level instead.

I tried digging through the sprockets code but haven't found a way to pass options to the js_compressor yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this issue:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2693

To put in simple terms, the given solution is:

```
# config.assets.js_compressor = :closure
require 'closure-compiler'
config.assets.js_compressor = Closure::Compiler.new(compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS')
```

Comment: Awesome, and embarrassing that I didn't find that myself via search.  Thanks, @alcides-queiroz-aguiar!